# Why aren't defined tokens recognized?

Tags: tokenize, antlr4

(using antlr-4.1-complete.jar)

I'm a newbie to ANTLR4, and created a simple grammar to test out what I learned.  I have found the results to be baffling, and I feel that there must be some basic concept I have (through all my reading) managed to not grasp.

Here is the grammar I defined:

```
grammar Gm;

// parser RULES
gmModel
    : obj+
    EOF
    ;

obj : objItem nameItem begin pairs end ;

objItem : OBJDECL ;
nameItem : OBJNAME ;
begin : OPEN ;
end : CLOSE ;
pairs : Pair+ ;

// LEXER RULES
OBJDECL : 'object' ;
OBJNAME : 'anotherobj' | 'testobj';
OPEN : '{' ;
CLOSE : '}' ;

fragment Var : ID_START (ID_CONT)+ ; // variable names start with an alpha
fragment Val : .*? ';' ; // values can be anything; capture everything up to the semicolon

Pair : Var Val ;

// fragments
fragment ID_START : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment ID_CONT : [-_a-zA-Z0-9] ;

WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

And here is the file I'm using as input. Each object has some number of name-value groups. Most of the time, it is a pair - there is only one value (space/tab delimited) but sometimes, there are two values following the name which is why it captures to the semi-colon

```
object testobj {
    testvar testval;
    v_B 1234.9876;
}

object anotherobj {
    name o611;
    phases "CN";
    v_A 2401.7771;
    groupid OBJTEST;
    timeslice 1 hour;
}
```

Even though I define

```
OBJDECL : 'object' ;
```

as a Lexer rule, it is not recognized as a token (TestRig basically shows several globs of text).
I even put it first, because I read that first-defined tokens take precedence.  I also read that the longest possible token is used, and maybe that's what's happening here, but in that case, I am failing to understand how to define useful tokens that can match strings of unpredictable length.

Any help you could offer would be hugely appreciated!

Also, a final comment after more tinkering: if I make the following two changes, the tokenizing is correct, EXCEPT that each pair only consists of a semicolon (where did the contents go?)

```
pairs : Pair+ ;
->
pairs : pair+ ;
```

and

```
Pair : Var Val ;
->
pair : ID_START (ID_CONT)+ .*? ';' ;
```

(in other words, make 'pair' a parser rule and replace the Var/Val fragments with an in-place definition)

From my limited understanding, I think that this change "improves" things because I am effectively removing the longest-possible token that was matchable before (Pair+), but I am still confused about why the name/value(s) are now missing altogether and I'm also (obviously!) still not clear on the recommended way of creating tokens in order to ensure they are not too greedy.

Why is only the semi-colon getting picked up now?  Not understanding that is one reason I feel I am still missing something basic.  (But in case you can't tell from my frequent edits, I have been thinking about this a lot and have read a lot of other previously-posted questions  and answers in order to not ask a dumb question, but I really am stumped.)

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right that "the longest possible regex is getting matched here". So when you are dealing with texts of unknown length you can make use of the lexical modes. May be the following grammars can parse your text properly.

Given below is the content of SampleObjectLexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar SampleObjectLexer;

OBJECTDECLARATION       :       'object';
OBJECTNAME              :       'testobj'|'anotherobj';
OPEN                    :       '{';
CLOSE                   :       '}';
NEWLINE                 :       [\r\n]  ->      skip;
WHITESPACE              :       [ \t]   ->      skip;

Var                     :       ID_START (ID_CONT)+ -> pushMode(VALMODE);
fragment ID_START       :       [a-zA-Z];
fragment ID_CONT        :       [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+;

mode VALMODE;

Val                     :       .*?';' -> popMode;
```

Given below is the content of SampleObjectParser.g4

```
parser grammar SampleObjectParser;

options {tokenVocab = SampleObjectLexer;}

gmModel :       obj+;
obj     :       OBJECTDECLARATION OBJECTNAME OPEN pair+ CLOSE;
pair    :       Var Val;
```

What we are doing in the lexer grammar is whenever we match the token Var, we instruct the Antlr Lexer to move to VALMODE within which we match the value and return back to the default mode using popMode. Since the default mode is unaware of the token Val (the one which was previously the longest possible regex), now within the default mode the lexer can match tokens like 'object', 'testobj', etc,.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ramg!!  I didn't include this in my original post, but I *had* tried experiementing with lexical modes as well, and it was not working for me.  In reading your post, I see that where I went wrong was that I put -> pushMode(READPAIR) after the OPEN brace, and tried to popMode on the CLOSE brace (that seemed most analogous to the XML examples I came across); your example helped me a lot.  Thanks again.